# Resiliency in Tiered Storage Spaces Volume

Tags: windows-10, cache, storage-spaces

I am using Windows 10

When creating an SSD tier and HDD tier with `New-StorageTier` command, I am able to set `ResiliencySettingName` (If unset, it seems to default to `Mirror`).

Then, when creating a Volume on these Tiers with `New-VirtualDisk -StorageTiers @($tier_ssd, $tier_hdd)`
I can once again provide `ResiliencySettingName`.

What does that affect?

I am looking to for example make something like "Mirror-accelerated parity" by having two SSDs in mirror on top of several HDDs in some parity setting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `New-VirtualDisk -StorageTiers` command creates its own Tiers based on the input Tiers.

For example, from my `SSDTier` and `HDDTier` it created `MySpace-SSDTier` and `MySpace-HDDTier`
(Without deleting the original tiers, I could then delete them with `Remove-StorageTier` to no ill effect)

Seems if I specify the `ResiliencySettingName`, it overrides the Resiliency of the input Tiers and creates both new Tiers with this Resiliency. Whereas if I don't specify, they inherit the Resiliency of the input Tiers, just as I needed.